# How to create an Objective C class/framework for re-use in the team

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, class-design

I have a class (that inherits from a base class) and also has image assets for some UI elements.  I would like to be able to wrap this up images and all, into a single file that can easily be added to future projects by myself and other members of the dev team.  Is there a way to do this? Adding a documentation file, a la Apple's own that responds to cmd click within XCode would be the icing on the cake.

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a static library... see the following [Tutorial](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html)

Comment: Hi Simon, this is great thanks, will have a go and see how I get on.  Any ideas on how to get documentation in there too?  Dave

Comment: Check out **Doxygen** to create the documentation. It also allows you to create Xcode-plugin-documentations, though I've never done that myself.

Comment: I'd second the Doxygen suggestion.